# Removing accents in string before inserting into SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

I have written the test below to remove accented characters from a string which works. I can't show any code from the program due to company policy which is why I have written the test of the offending code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String name = "Damián";

        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine(removeAccents(name));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string removeAccents(string text)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(text));
    }
}
```

However, when I try insert the new string into a database the accented characters re-appear in the data. I am using parameterised SqlCommand to insert the data. The accents don't exist in the data when I debug the program, only when the command has been executed. Would it be a case of changing the text encoding?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The above code works with removing the accents and produces the output:

Damián

Damian

_

However, when the name is entered in the database it contains the 'á' again.

Comment: why would you want to drop the accents in the first place? SQL server can perform non-accent sensitive comparisons by specifying the collation...

Comment: total guess as we cant see the actual code - are you inserting the string you are passing into your removeAccents method, and not the string that is being returned from it?

Comment: Is it not possible to remove the accents from a string, before inserting then to a database?

Comment: I have decided to go the path of adding names with accents to the database and remove them upon retrieval

Comment: Adam - of course it is possible - so its going to be down to an error in your code. Try this - assign the return from your removeAccents method to a brand new string and insert that - don't use the name variable again. see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your "removeAccents" function needs a little work.

Let's push it forward a couple of steps -

```
static string RemoveAccents(string text) 
{
    var normalized = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var character in normalized)
    {
        var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(character);
        if (unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            builder.Append(character);
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

Let's see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this works the same as my code. This issue is once the data has been entered in the database it contains accents again.

Comment: That's very, very odd.  I realize it's probably rude to even suggest it, but are you certain you're writing the normalized string to the database?

Comment: Indeed, I am certain that I am writing the normalised string in the database. There are two strings, one normalised and one not which are used in different applications. I have gone down the path of normalising the data in the application upon retrieval from the database.